# Can't create SOAP client in Netbeans existing project

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, webservice-client

I'm trying to follow these tutorials on how to get Netbeans (v 7.1.1) to automatically create a SOAP web service client:

- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html
- http://blog.jdevelop.eu/2008/02/27/creating-soap-web-services-with-netbeans-6/

But I can't seem to find the `Web Service from WSDL` file type (as shown below) on some of my projects.
[image: Web Service from WSDL file type]

Some of my projects do display that file type and some don't.  The particular project for which I need to create the SOAP client does NOT list that file type.  Why would this be?

They are all Web Application projects as far as I know of (Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate frameworks).  I checked them out of subversion from Netbeans projects created by other programmers.  It's possible that the original Netbeans project was created in a previous version of Netbeans - not sure if this matters.

How do I get the `Web Service from WSDL` new file type to show up for my existing project?

Comment: Tutorial explains. "Web Application" project.

Comment: @Alfabravo: they are all Web Application projects as far as I know of.  Added a bit more detail in the question with regards to this.

Answer (score 2):

'Web Service from WSDL' option only comes when you choose to create Web projects. In the desktop projects(Java), there is a option 'Web Service Client' in which you can specify the wsdl URL and it will create the web service references for you.

Comment: Not sure how the Netbeans project was initially created or if there's a way to check what the "project type" is, but I don't see the option for a 'Web Service Client' either.  I only see RESTful web services options.